# How can I make my bot delete part of this json file

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot remove data from a json file after the command is sent but I'm having difficulty deleting the one piece of data from the json file. It'd be great if someone could help me out with this.

```
@client.command(name='redeem', pass_content=True)
async def redeem(message, code):
  with open('keys.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    if code in data:
      ----delete some json data here
      role = message.guild.get_role(910056424812466176)
      await message.author.add_roles(role)
      await message.author.send("message here")
      hwidchannel = client.get_channel(909907655324205088)
      def check(m):
        print("message detected")
        if isinstance(m.channel, 
        discord.channel.DMChannel):
          print("is dm")
          if  m.author.id == message.author.id:
            print("correct user")
            return hwidchannel == hwidchannel
      msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
      await message.author.send('Please be patient as your purchase is reviewed.')
      await hwidchannel.send('Hwid is {.content}'.format(msg))
      await hwidchannel.send('Userid is {.author.id}'.format(msg))
    else:
      await message.author.send("Invalid Code")
```

Json file:

```
{
  "3fswgtwdfe":"wasd",
  "29jyf382ff":"wasd"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest take on this is:

```
data['urcode']=None
```

But will probably cause some errors when using the data.
You can use the data.pop() instead:

```
data.pop("urcode")
```

Then update the file:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    #Indent is optional, just makes the file look cleaner.
```